# How to listen to a 3x3 mixtured waves in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a sound file (3x3_Mixture.wav)=sound33 which includes 3 different sound waves mixed with each other, I made a code to separate the 3 different sound waves by using fast-ICA and the natural gradient algorithm.
Now I want to listen to the file 3x3_Mixture.wav in matlab.
When I write `sound(sound33)` in the command window and then press enter I get the following error message: `Only one- and two-channel audio supported.`
How can I listen to 3x3_Mixture.wav in matlab when it has three sound waves, which command should I use?

Comment: Have you thought to sum the three different waveform and then listen to the sum?

Comment: No brother ... the file was already made of mixed three sound waves ... My task is to separate them ...But now I want to listen to the file before the separation ...thanks

Comment: I don't know, maybe what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: I could do this : sound(sound33(1,:)) and I listened to it ... sound33 is the file with mixed waves ...

Comment: What `size()` does the loaded 3x3_Mixture.wav have? Is it three channels?

Comment: yes it is three channels .. size(sound33) = 3   x    48000

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with more than two channels in a wave file or vector there are basically a few options. The first one is downmixing the channels into one or two vectors. You could to so by summing over the channels or multiplying them with each other (element-wise multiplication, obviously).

Another one is to listen to the file by playing back the channels one by one or in pairs of two.

But if your audio hardware consists of more than two audio channels (simply-put an audio interface with >2 channels) my advise would be to use better tools than the included `sound` or `soundsc` commands of Matlab. Use for example [Msound](https://github.com/TGM-Oldenburg/Msound/), a audio playback and recording tool utilizing the PortAudio framework to output up to 64 channels of audio to capable hardware.